# Generalized Likelihood Ratio Test - Why is the denominator a union

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio

For GLRT, the ratio is:

$$
\Lambda^* = \frac{\max_{\theta \in \omega_0} L(\theta)}{\max_{\theta \in \omega_1}L(\theta)}
$$

but we instead use:

$$
\Lambda = \frac{\max_{\theta \in \omega_0}L(\theta)}{\max_{\theta \in \omega_0 \cup \omega_1}L(\theta)}
$$

I'm not understanding what the rationale behind this is and would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: Isn't the second one $\Lambda$ the standard definition of likelihood ratio in hypotheses testing theory?

Comment: I believe it's the first one for neyman pearson and uniformally most powerful. glrt uses the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean there is a null hypothesis stating that the parameter $\theta$ is in $\omega_0$ and $\omega_1$ is just the complement of $\omega_0$.

The unconstrained MLE for $\theta$ is $$\widehat{\theta\,} = \operatorname*{argmax}_{\theta\,\in\,\omega_0\, \cup\,\omega_1} L(\theta).$$

If $\widehat{\theta\,} \in\omega_0$ then, according to what you say "we instead use", the ratio

$$
\Lambda = \frac{\max_{\theta\,\in\,\omega_0} L(\theta)}{\max_{\theta\,\in\,\omega_0\,\cup\,\omega_1} L(\theta)}
$$

is equal to $1.$ Thus it is only when there is some evidence against the null hypothesis that $\Lambda<1.$ The stronger the evidence against the null hypothesis, the smaller $\Lambda$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm wondering why we use the union for an unconstrained MLE instead of the MLE for w1

Comment: @user6132211 : I wanted a function that is equal to $1$ when there is no evidence against the null hypothesis and less than $1$ otherwise.